# Nextjs not running on root url path

Tags: next.js

I am deploying a nextjs app on Azure Static Web Apps and there is an issue loading the root url path, the index.html file is only loaded without triggering nextjs. However when loading a subpath (e.g. root.com/mypath/ ) the app loads successfully. Both root path and subpaths work fine on localhost.

The app is configured using the catch-all route [...params].tsx along with the Index.tsx file located under the pages folder. Also using SSR.

Any idea why loading the app on the root path is not working when it works for subpaths?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by removing index.html from the public folder and adding instead document.tsx to the pages folder.